# How to call this script in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a script file (service-graph.js) that I would like to make it work in wordpress, I have pretty basic knowlogdge of javascript so I'm not sure if the script would work in wordpress, the content is the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.pathname;
var path = url.split('/');

jQuery('.curve-item.' + path[2]).addClass('default');

if (path[2] == 'blueprint')
    jQuery('.overview-graph .middle-item').addClass('default');

jQuery('.curve-item .logo').hover(
    function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('default')) return;
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass('on');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('on');
    }
).css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function () {
    location.href = '/services/' + jQuery(this).parent('.curve-item').data('target');
});

jQuery('.overview-graph .middle-item').on('click', function () {
    location.href = '/services/blueprint';
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

});

And I using this function to call the script on functions.php

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('service-graph', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/service-graph.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('service-graph');
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Comment: Didn't you test it yet ? Cause I understood like that from your question. And if you have this page called /services etc. it should work because it's just a js file, it doesn't work differently in wordpress.

Comment: Yes, I've tested but it doesn't work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The script shouldn't need to be called further within WordPress.  Have you checked your browser resources to make sure that service-graph.js and jQuery are being loaded?  I have a feeling it's a jQuery version mismatch.